# Prove that $g^{jm}\nabla_i\mathrm{R}_{jklm} = \nabla_i(g^{jm}\mathrm{R}_{jklm}) = \nabla_i\mathrm{R}_{kl}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, so that we have the Riemannian connection $\nabla$, and in local coordinates $(x^i)$, we can define $\mathrm{R}_{ijkl} = \langle\mathrm{R}(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k,\partial_l\rangle$, $\mathrm{R}_{kl} = g^{il}\mathrm{R}_{ijkl}$, and for a covariant $r$-tensor field $$F = F_{i_1\ldots i_r}\mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathrm{d}x^{i_r}$$ we can set $\nabla_j F_{i_1\ldots i_r} = (\nabla_{\partial_j}F)(\partial_{i_1},\ldots,\partial_{i_r})$. I wish to prove that$$g^{jm}\nabla_i\mathrm{R}_{jklm} = \nabla_i(g^{jm}\mathrm{R}_{jklm}) = \nabla_i\mathrm{R}_{kl}.$$

Here is my work so far: \begin{align*}
\nabla_i(g^{jm}R_{jklm}) &= \partial_i(g^{jm}R_{jklm}) - g^{jm}\Gamma_{ik}^s\mathrm{R}_{jslm} - g^{jm}\Gamma_{il}^s\mathrm{R}_{jksm} \\
&= \mathrm{R}_{jklm}\partial_i g^{jm} + g^{jm}\partial_i \mathrm{R}_{jklm} - g^{jm}\Gamma_{ik}^s\mathrm{R}_{jslm} - g^{jm}\Gamma_{il}^s\mathrm{R}_{jksm} \\
&= g^{jm}\nabla_i\mathrm{R}_{jklm} + \mathrm{R}_{jklm}\partial_i g^{jm} + g^{jm}\Gamma_{ij}^s\mathrm{R}_{sklm} + g^{jm}\Gamma_{im}^s\mathrm{R}_{jkls} \\
&= g^{jm}\nabla_i\mathrm{R}_{jklm} + \mathrm{R}_{jklm}\partial_i g^{jm} + \Gamma_{ij}^s\mathrm{R}_{skl}^j + \Gamma_{im}^s\mathrm{R}_{slk}^j
\end{align*}

so that I wish to show that $$\mathrm{R}_{jklm}\partial_i g^{jm} + \Gamma_{ij}^s\mathrm{R}_{skl}^j + \Gamma_{im}^s\mathrm{R}_{slk}^j= 0$$ but I don't see an easy way of doing this (besides expanding everything into the full form, which I would ideally like to avoid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your connection is metric compatible, you know that $\nabla_m g_{jk} = 0$.

Applying the Leibnitz rule to both sides of the equation $g^{ij}g_{jk} = \delta^i_k$, we also find that
$$\nabla_m g^{ij} = 0.$$

But then, applying the Leibnitz rule once more, we have
$$\nabla_i(g^{jm}R_{jklm}) = g^{jm}\nabla_iR_{jklm} + R_{jklm} \nabla_ig^{jm}=g^{jm}\nabla_i(R_{jklm}). $$

Comment: P.S. I realised I assumed you're using the Levi-Civita connection! (That's how the Riemann tensor in my masters course, but I suppose you don't have to do this.) If you're not using the Levi-Civita connection, then I'm afraid I don't know, but perhaps an expert can answer...

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I meant by "Riemannian connection".

Comment: Are you using $\nabla_i$ to mean $\partial_i$ here?

Comment: No, I mean the covariant derivative.

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: What is the Leibniz rule for covariant differentiation then?

Comment: Same as for ordinary derivatives. Example: $\nabla_i(v^{jk}w_{lm}) = \nabla_i v^{jk} w_{lm} + v^{jk} \nabla_iw_{lm}$.

Comment: By $\nabla_i w_{lm}$ do you mean $w_{lm;i}$, or do you mean $\nabla_{\partial_i} w_{lm}$? Because if you mean the first thing, I don't quite see how that's obvious.

Comment: $w_{lm;i}$ and $\nabla_{\partial_i} w_{lm}$ are the same thing, by definition!

Comment: Moreover, the reason why the covariant derivative of tensors is defined the way it is is precisely so that the Leibnitz rule holds!

Comment: But, for a covariant $4$-tensor $$F = F_{ijkl}\mathrm{d}x^i\otimes\mathrm{d}x^j\otimes\mathrm{d}x^k\otimes\mathrm{d}x^l$$ we have that $$F_{ijkl;m} = \nabla_m F_{ijkl} := (\nabla_{\partial_m}F)(\partial_i,\partial_j,\partial_k,\partial_l) = \partial_m F_{ijkl} - F(\nabla_{\partial_m}\partial_i,\partial_j,\partial_k,\partial_l) - F(\partial_i,\nabla_{\partial_m}\partial_j,\partial_k,\partial_l) - \ldots$$

Comment: Jack Lee's book states that $\nabla_{\partial_i} = \partial_i$ on scalar fields, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55555/discussion-between-kenny-wong-and-monstrous-moonshine).